# Changing text into JSON

Tags: json, jq

Example of input data (`^`-delimited fields):

```
C-11^Mark^Docking AWS
C-12^Mark^Docking AWS
C-13^Lay^Ploting
C-14^Lay^Ploting
C-15^Lay^Ploting
C-16^Vincent^GPU Calc
C-17^Vincent^GPU Calc
C-18^Vincent^GPU Calc
C-19^Vincent^GPU Calc
```

I use this command:

```bsh
 jq -Rn '
    [inputs | select(. != "") / "^"]
    | reduce .[] as [$container, $user, $job] ({};
      .[$job] += [{$user, $container}]
    )
    'test.csv > test.json
```

I correctly get the following JSON output:

```json
 "Docking AWS\r": [
    {
      "user": "Mark",
      "container": "C-11"
    },
    {
      "user": "Mark",
      "container": "C-12"
    }
  ],
```

... but I want this formatted like the following JSON:

```json
Docking AWS
user: Mark
container: C-11,C-12


 "Docking AWS\r": [
    {
      "user": "Mark",
      "container": "C-11","C12"
    },
```

How may I achieve this?

++edit++

```
{
  "job": "Docking AWS",
  "user": "Mark",
  "container": [
    "C-11",
    "C-12"
 ]
}
```

i want this format how to convert?

Comment: Which output is the one you want? Please [edit] your question so there's just the one required output. You don't need to say "++edit++" or "update" because there's an edit history available. Just make the question easy to read and self-consistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want something like the following as your result:

```json
{
  "Docking AWS": {
    "user": "Mark",
    "container": [
      "C-11",
      "C-12"
    ]
  },
  "Ploting": {
    "user": "Lay",
    "container": [
      "C-13",
      "C-14",
      "C-15"
    ]
  },
  "GPU Calc": {
    "user": "Vincent",
    "container": [
      "C-16",
      "C-17",
      "C-18",
      "C-19"
    ]
  }
}
```

This may be had by using `reduce` to build up the resulting structure from the split up substrings of the original lines:

```bsh
jq -Rn '
    reduce ( inputs / "^" ) as [$container,$user,$job] ({}; 
        .[$job] |= ( .user      |=   $user |
                     .container += [ $container ] )
    )' file
```

This uses `reduce` to read the input and split it into short arrays of three elements each.   Starting with an empty object, new keys are added by updating sub-objects.  The sub-object referred to by the `$job` key is updated by setting the `user` key to `$user` and by adding `$container` to the array `container` in the object.

The main differences between this and your code is that I'm updating objects in the result rather than just adding them for each input line. I'm also treating `.[$job].container` as an array.

Since you seem to be working with DOS text files, you may want to either convert your input data to Unix text files using `dos2unix`, or remove the carriage-return character from the end of each line manually with `jq` (change `inputs / "^"` into `inputs | rtrimstr("\r") / "^"`).

---

The revised question, the way I interpret it, asks to create a top-level array of jobs rather than to put each job as a key in a top-level object.  This is a matter of adjusting the `reduce` call a bit to include a `job` key that gets the `$job` string as value, and then putting the objects that `reduce` creates into an array:

```bsh
jq -Rn '
    reduce ( inputs / "^" ) as [$container,$user,$job] ({}; 
        .[$job] |= ( .job       |=   $job  |
                     .user      |=   $user |
                     .container += [ $container ] )
    ) | [ .[] ]' file
```

Given the data in the question, this would generate

```json
[
  {
    "job": "Docking AWS",
    "user": "Mark",
    "container": [
      "C-11",
      "C-12"
    ]
  },
  {
    "job": "Ploting",
    "user": "Lay",
    "container": [
      "C-13",
      "C-14",
      "C-15"
    ]
  },
  {
    "job": "GPU Calc",
    "user": "Vincent",
    "container": [
      "C-16",
      "C-17",
      "C-18",
      "C-19"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you answer the revised question?

Comment: @morris__ See updated answer.