# how to txt -> json convert?

Tags: linux, json, jq

```
C-11^Mark^Docking AWS
C-12^Mark^Docking AWS
C-13^Lay^Ploting
C-14^Lay^Ploting
C-15^Lay^Ploting
C-16^Vincent^GPU Calc
C-17^Vincent^GPU Calc
C-18^Vincent^GPU Calc
C-19^Vincent^GPU Calc
```

I use this command:

```
jq -Rn '
    [inputs | select(. != "") / "^"]
    | reduce .[] as [$container, $user, $job] ({};
      .[$job] += [{$user, $container}]
    )
    'test.csv > test.json
```

i want this format data

```
{
  "job": "Docking AWS",
  "user": "Mark",
  "container": [
    "C-11",
    "C-12"
 ]
}
```

.
.
.

How may I achieve this?

Comment: How is this different from [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/686966/70524)?

Comment: output is slightly different

Comment: you then need to revert back your previous question's last edit

Comment: Next time, please don't ask two of the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was originally an adjustment to [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/686966/70524), to which I provided [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/687090/493832).  I also addressed the adjusted question there.

The shell code that I came up with is the following:

```bsh
jq -Rn '
    reduce ( inputs / "^" ) as [$container,$user,$job] ({}; 
        .[$job] |= ( .job       |=   $job  |
                     .user      |=   $user |
                     .container += [ $container ] )
    ) | [ .[] ]' file
```

This uses `reduce` to create objects as sub-objects in a top-level object, each one keyed by the job string.  When all data has been processed in this manner, the sub-objects are expanded into a top-level array.

Given the data in the question, this generates the following JSON document:

```json
[
  {
    "job": "Docking AWS",
    "user": "Mark",
    "container": [
      "C-11",
      "C-12"
    ]
  },
  {
    "job": "Ploting",
    "user": "Lay",
    "container": [
      "C-13",
      "C-14",
      "C-15"
    ]
  },
  {
    "job": "GPU Calc",
    "user": "Vincent",
    "container": [
      "C-16",
      "C-17",
      "C-18",
      "C-19"
    ]
  }
]
```